# Nothing will echo inside my foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, pdo, foreach

Im running into this issue and ive never had it before.

For some reason when i go to run my php script anything inside or even after this foreach loop doesn't get echoed to the page which is weird.

below this outside the loop I have a script to email me some information, but even that wont send anything.

Any idea why this foreach could be failing, all the $fetch data is correct as I can echo it all out just before.

```
echo "<strong> - FLAGGED FOR DELETION </strong>";       
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM client_links WHERE clid = '.$fetch['clid'].' AND link = "'.$fetch['url'].'" and cwid = '.$fetch['cwid'].' ') as $row){        
                echo "FOREACH IS WORKING";
```

Cheers in advance!

Comment: PLEASE place `$db->query('SELECT * FROM client_links WHERE clid = '.$fetch['clid'].' AND link = "'.$fetch['url'].'" and cwid = '.$fetch['cwid'].' ')` outside the loop in a variable. That is horrible!

Comment: `foreach` isn't failing, `$db->query()` probably isn't returning anything you can loop over.  Who knows though since we can't read minds and don't know what DB API you're using.  Also, you're likely wide open to SQL injection attacks since you are concatenating data directly into your query.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely!

Comment: Probably query fails and returns FALSE.

Comment: @Brad Its an internal system that only I have access to.

Comment: @Duenna How do you expect us to help you then without any clue at all what `$db->query()` returns?  And, SQL injection problems aren't just security problems.  Have fun when someone puts a quote mark in a field somewhere.

Comment: @Brad magic - fly away..

Comment: @Duenna `$result = $db->query(".....");` then `var_dump($result);` then what does that return?

Comment: @PatrickQ She echoed her `$fetch` data and says it's correct.  The problem is that she won't tell us what `$db->query()` returns.

Comment: @Brad Ah, missed that line

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the issue was that one of my includes at the top of the script was overriding $db